# 80s movie where the main character has fast healing or is immune to harm

Tags: story-identification, movie

The details of this movie are specially fuzzy on my mind.

I saw it at some point in the 80s I think and I can only remember very vague facts.

- Main character has immunity to harm. I “think” is more like super fast healing, à la Wolverine.
- At one point in the movie he has to go from one place to another and there’s a remark in the sense since he doesn’t fatigue, he’ll be able to run at peak human velocity all the way and hence make it in time. I seem to recall he runs through a forest and it is elated to save his son.
- There’s a girl, some kind of scientist that’s helping him but I don’t think it was the mother.
- The main character has a son. In his early teens.
- At the end of the movie, this is the scene I remember more vividly, the son wants to know if he’s inherited the healing powers of his dad, so he purposely cuts himself on the hand washing on the kitchen sink. The main character comes running to find him holding the hand under water and he confesses what he has done and why. When he shows the hand, the injury is gone, implying he does, indeed, share his dad’s ability.

Comment: I want to say that I remember the bit with the son cutting his hand...

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212533/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt - Similar themes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Magical World of Disney: I-Man* (1986)?

From [IMDb](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0091248/reviews):

> When a truck carrying a sample of alien gas is ran off the road, the container springs a leak. A man and his son is exposed to the gas in an attempt to rescue the driver and a scientist. Discovering the gas has a strange effect on him. **He and his son can heal instantly, now wanted by the elderly crime lord who wanted the gas for just that reason.** They must discover a way to keep ahead of him and his men. Their only weakness is long term exposure to complete darkness will kill them. This was only a pilot for a series that never made it. Just Like "Exo-Man" and "The Man With The Power".

The scene with the handcut starts at 28'20 below (so, not quite the end):

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction movie healing power -wolverine site:imdb.com/title`, page 4 of the results.

Comment: I’m almost sure this is the one

Comment: Impressed that the -wolverine actually achieved something. Not having a reference to Wolverine stuffed into a description somewhere on the page is surprising.